# Create dictionary from list when keys are embedded in list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of college towns with corresponding states in the U.S. I want to create a dataframe with two columns one for 'State' and the other 'RegionName'.  The dataframe should look like this:

```
    DataFrame( [ ["Alabama", "Auburn"], ["Alabama", "Troy"], 
    ["Alabama", "Tuscaloosa"], ["Alabama", "Tuskegee"], ["Alaska", 
    "Fairbanks"], ["Arizona", "Flagstaff"], ["Arizona", "Tempe"], ["Arizona", 
    "Tucson"] ], 
    columns=["State", "RegionName"]  )
```

The problem is I have a list with the States and RegionNames together, with the corresponding RegionNames following after the State name in the list like this:

```
['Alabama',
 'Auburn','Troy','Tuscaloosa','Tuskegee',
'Alaska','Fairbanks',
 'Arizona','Flagstaff','Tempe','Tucson']
```

I have been looking at examples and I am currently stuck on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need create the list of states here, then using `ffill` with `mask` to split the original single columns dataframe

```
df['RegionName']=df.State
df.State=df.State.where(df.State.isin(States)).ffill()
df=df.loc[df.State!=df.RegionName]
df
Out[80]: 
      State  RegionName
1   Alabama      Auburn
2   Alabama        Troy
3   Alabama  Tuscaloosa
4   Alabama    Tuskegee
6    Alaska   Fairbanks
8   Arizona   Flagstaff
9   Arizona       Tempe
10  Arizona      Tucson
```

Data Input

```
States=['Alabama','Alaska','Arizona'] 
l=['Alabama',
  'Auburn','Troy','Tuscaloosa','Tuskegee',
  'Alaska','Fairbanks',
  'Arizona','Flagstaff','Tempe','Tucson']
df=pd.DataFrame(l,columns=['State'])
```